# How to run unit tests in Jenkins in separate Docker containers?

Tags: docker, jenkins, python-unittest

In our codebase, we have multiple neural networks (classification, object detection, etc.) for which we have written some unit tests which we want to run in Jenkins at some specified point (the specific point is not relevant, e.g. whenever we merge some feature branch in the master branch).

The issue is that due to external constraints, each neural net needs another version of keras/tensorflow and a few other packages, so we cannot run them all in the same Jenkins environment. The obvious solution to this is Docker containers (we have specialized Docker images for each one) and ideally we would want to tell Jenkins to execute each  unittest in a Docker container that we specify beforehand.

Does anyone know how to do that with Jenkins? I searched online, but the solutions I have found seem a bit hacky to me.

Comment: As you've described it, you might see if Python virtual environments fit your need: they're simpler than Docker containers, don't require complicated filesystem machinations or administrator permissions, and still allow a separate disjoint set of packages per installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a candidate for Jenkins pipelines, [especially docker agents](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/)

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Back-end') {
            agent {
                docker { image 'maven:3-alpine' }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'mvn --version'
            }
        }
        stage('Front-end') {
            agent {
                docker { image 'node:7-alpine' }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'node --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This allows for the actual Jenkins agent to spin up a docker container to do the work. You say you have images already so you're most of the way.

Comment: How about with a workflow that builds a docker image for a component and then needs to run the unit/integration tests for that component. (e.g. you don't have the docker images before, as they are build during that specific workflow)

Comment: You should ask a new question for a new topic. However, an opinionated way of doing it is to use the 3 musketeers pattern https://3musketeers.io/ and have a simple Jenkinsfile wrapper round your makefile